# Setup version for module 'Namespace_Modulename' is not specified : Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I am creating an module in **Magento 2 ( ver. 2.0.0)**. I have registered my module in **app/etc/config.xml**

```
'Namespace_Modulename => 1,
```

My `module.xml` file under **app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/module.xml**

**module.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.1"/> 
</config>
```

When I run my module Magento 2 generate below error :

> Setup version for module 'Namespace_Modulename' is not specified

My module was working fine before stable release, after upgraded to stable release I start getting this error. I searched lot on google before adding here, got some results but none of then working for me.

Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in **module.xml**:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Namespace_Modulename" schema_version="2.0.1" setup_version="2.0.1"/> 
</config>
```

Add `registration.php` and `composer.json` in your module.

/app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/code/Namespace/Module/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "namespace/module",
    "description": "namespace",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"    
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Namespace/Module"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "namespace\\module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Now run `magento setup:upgrade` and schema upgrade if applicable.

Now clear all caches and var/generation folder. `Login to admin panel > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`. Your module should be listed here now.

Comment: How can i run schema upgrade?

Comment: php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Also Wrong file/folder permission can cause this error

```
chmod 775 /magento/app/code/vendorname/modulename -R
```